# How to group all contiguous even numbers into a 2D array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I've the following array of numbers:

```
[10, 12, 23, 17, 14, 15, 50, 72, 26, 33]
```

And I want to group all even numbers that appear together, as below:

```
[ [ 10, 12 ], [ 14 ], [ 50, 72, 26 ] ]
```

I'm able to filter out the even numbers, but I'm unable to group the contiguous ones together. I think `reduce` can be used here, but I'm unable to understand how, any help is highly appreciated.

```
const nums = [10, 12, 23, 17, 14, 15, 50, 72, 26, 33];
const result = nums.map((n, i) => (n % 2 === 0 ? [n] : []));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

For every number that is even, do the following:

1. [Push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) an empty array into the resultant array if the last number was *not* even (i.e. it was odd).
2. Get the last group in the resultant array using [Array.prototype.at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) and then `push` the current number into this group.

```js
const 
  nums = [10, 12, 23, 17, 14, 15, 50, 72, 26, 33],
  result = nums.reduce((res, num, i) => {
    if (!(num & 1)) {
      if (!i || nums[i - 1] & 1) {
        res.push([]);
      }
      res.at(-1).push(num);
    }
    return res;
  }, []);

console.log(result);
```

**Note:** I've used the [Bitwise AND (&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_AND) operator to check if a number is even or odd, you could also use the [Remainder operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder).